# Problems With Opening Room Gamemaker

Tags: game-maker

In Gamemaker, I have a main menu room, and hitting start takes you to the gameplay room. When testing it, it did not take me to the gameplay room. I made it load into the problem room first, and all it loaded was a black screen. I also noticed when I looked in the console it was said:

> RequestStats - failed: 2

What's causing this and how do I fix it?

Here is my game:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xWota0WfzcwvYGHY4zFVwS0vXDwNQfDp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found out what caused the problem, but I deleted the room, then created it again and readded all the objects, and it fixed the issue. The error in the console has not gone away, but the room loads properly.